# LaTeX beamer presentation-package 16:9 aspect ratio?

Tags: beamer, paper-size

I'm programming a presentation in LaTeX using the `beamer` class.

However, it defaults to 4:3 aspect ratio slides, while everything I use is 16:9. Is there an easy way to change this using a command or two?

Comment: In addition to the beamer aspectratio option, I am finding I need to use the pdfcrop command: pdfcrop $PDF $PDFCROPPED where $PDF and $PDFCROPPED are environment variables containing your input and output file names. This crops the top and bottom so that full screen mode really uses a full 16:9 screen.

Comment: @MattFulkerson I do not understand your comment and I strongly believe there is a misunderstanding on your end. There is no need to crop the pdf after the creation in order to have the correct aspect ratio.

Answer (score 413):

It looks like the current version of `beamer` supports **`aspectratio` option**.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
```

should do exactly that. Other possible values are: 1610, 149, 54, 43 and 32.

By default, it is to 128mm by 96mm(4:3).

Ensure that you do not also use `\geometry{paperwidth=XX,paperheight=YY}` into the same tex file, otherwise `aspectratio` may be ignored.

**edited to add**:
As of the 2022 (so TeXLive users will need to have TeXLive 2022), arbitrary aspect ratios are available. Two-digit numbers after `aspectratio=` will be interpreted as X:Y, three-digit numbers as XX:Y and four digit as XX:YY.

Comment: Hi, could it be possible to have a wide screen aspect ratio for an EEE pc projection (1024/600 or 10:6 has I've read on the net) ?

Comment: still the best answer in 2021 -  thanks!

Comment: I edited the answer so that it is pushed to the top (when "newest first" is the order criteria) because it is the best answer IMHO.

Comment: @Julien See the edited version of the answer which indicates new flexibility on the aspect ratio.

Comment: Thanks @Alexey, you saved my day

Answer (score 26):

Alexey's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14339/40838) is the most correct one.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
```

To get this in emacs orgmode, make this line be your `#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS`

```
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [aspectratio=169]
```

I added this to my earlier setting, `smaller`, like this:

```
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [smaller,aspectratio=169]
```

Answer (score 20):

According to [A Beamer Quickstart](http://userpages.umbc.edu/~rostamia/beamer/quickstart-Z-H-24.html#node_sec_24), "The size of a Beamer slide is 128mm by 96mm. These dimensions are fixed and should not be changed."

However, there is a [beamerposter](http://www-i6.informatik.rwth-aachen.de/~dreuw/latexbeamerposter.php#169-slides) package which allows a 16:9 ratio.

Comment: Yes, that's better than my `\setbeamersize{...}` hack! +1

Comment: That part of the documentation is actually out of date.

Answer (score 19):

As already mentioned, the size is fixed to a ratio of 4:3. However, you can decrease the right and left margin like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.1em}  % <- like this
\setbeamersize{text margin right=0.1em} % <- like this

\title{The title of this presentation}
\author{Bart Kiers}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

  \frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

which will make your slides look like:

[image]

instead of:

[image]

**EDIT:**

And as neilfws mentioned, try the `beamerposter` package.

The following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=16,height=9,scale=0.5,debug]{beamerposter} 

\title{The title of this presentation}
\author{Bart Kiers}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

  \frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Answer (score 16):

### New Answer in 2022

- The question was asked originally in 2010.
- In the meantime, there are new features in `beamer` that are relevant to the question.
- Now you can use **arbitrary** `aspectratio = xxxx` with `xxxx = 1609` or `xxxx = 1610` for example.
- **New:** The option `aspectratio` is not limited to a fixed list of pre-defined ratios anymore, instead, the ratio is calculated on the fly based on the value of `xxxx`.
- The feature is available in [TeXLive 2022 and after](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/3659a643cd3ac179bf526db33269e6a9102d1768). This means that it is not available on Overleaf as of now (2022-05).

[image]

*PS: Power-user `samcarter` made me aware of this new feature on a chat on https://topanswers.xyz/tex. `samcarter` actually implemented the feature in `beamer`!*

---

```
\documentclass[aspectratio = 1610]{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{aspectratio = 1610}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14339/87876), this feature has been available since 2010.

Comment: @vtfs271232 Back then only predefined ratios were possible. Now you can use arbitrary ratios, e. g. 1020 for 10:20 etc

Comment: I see. Thank you.